# Use SubString as Function in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

I tried to fetch the character in Roku.
Here I apply a static way and string find successfully.

```
string = "HelloRokuIamHere"
if Instr(string, "Roku") > 0 then
   ?"String is Found"
else
   ?"String is Not Found"
end if
```

Here I get a string as dynamic. So Every time not give static value. So, I tried to substring like below. Is it Possible like that or any other way?

```
string = "HelloRokuIamHere"
?"substring(string,5,8) ' here I tried to display "Roku"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function for finding and extracting substrings in BrightScript is `mid()`, you can either use the [Global String Function](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/language/global-string-functions.md#mids-as-string-p-as-integer-n-as-integer-as-string) or the [ifStringOps Interface Function](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifstringops.md#midstart_index-as-integer-num_chars-as-integer-as-string)

Usage

```
string = "HelloRokuIamHere"
? Mid(string, 6, 4) ' prints "Roku"
? string.mid(5, 4) ' also prints "Roku"
```